Py2exe with cx_oracle. Exe won't run on other computers
I created a short script that connects to an Oracle db and pulls some data. This works on my PC as I have everything installed E.g. pycharm with cx_oracle etc.
I want to be able to run this on other devices without the need installing other software.
I used py2exe to create an executable which works fine on my pc however when I try running it on another device I received an error DPI-1047: CANNOT LOCATE A 64-BIT ORACLE CLIENT LIBRARY. Module could not be found
I understand the error but I was hoping everything that is needed to run the exe would be exported by using py2exe. I don't want others to have the hassle of installing additional software
Advice on how to get around this or if there is a different option
Zipped the entire dist folder , extracted onto another PC and attempted to run exe
Used the recommended py2exe

Use python-oracledb (pip install oracledb) instead of cx_Oracle
From the documentation:

By default, python-oracledb runs in a ‘Thin’ mode which connects directly to Oracle Database. This mode does not need Oracle Client libraries. ...
cx_Oracle always runs in a Thick mode using Oracle Client libraries.

Edit: to be clear, as @thatjeffsmith points out, oracledb has supplanted cx_Oracle:

New projects should install python-oracledb instead of cx_Oracle.


Doing this worked however I did have to import a few things vvid, cryptography, _cffi_backend

cx_oracle id deprecated, python-oracledb is the way forward

Technically python-oracledb is just the new name for cx_Oracle. All new releases are in the python-oracledb namespace.  See A Celebration of Python and Oracle Database which lists some of the many enhancements in python-oracledb since the final release in the cx_Oracle namespace.
